# BluetoothAdapter ActionDiscoveryFinished

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bluetooth

I just started to take a look at xamarin and now I want to scan for bluetooth-devices. Therefor I use the following code:

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
bluetoothAdapter.StartDiscovery();
```

And I have the following `class` for getting the result:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new [] {BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryFinished})]
public class BluetoothReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public BluetoothReceiver()
    {

    }

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryFinished.Equals(intent.Action))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I've also set the permissions for my app to `BLUETOOTH` and `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN`. Everything just works fine and the `OnReceive`-Method is called correctly. My problem now is: How do I get the found devices from the parameters of the OnReceive-Method?

Answer (score 1):

`ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED` doesn't tell you anything other than the discovery action has finished. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED

If you wanted to grab devices from the scan, you should read what `startDiscovery()` has to say regarding finding devices:

> The discovery process usually involves an inquiry scan of about 12 seconds, followed by a page scan of each new device to retrieve its Bluetooth name.
>
> This is an asynchronous call, it will return immediately. Register for ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED and ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED intents to determine exactly when the discovery starts and completes. Register for ACTION_FOUND to be notified as remote Bluetooth devices are found.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startDiscovery()

Thus you should use `ACTION_FOUND` and parse the `EXTRA_DEVICE` for devices:

> Broadcast Action: Remote device discovered.
>
> Sent when a remote device is found during discovery.
>
> Always contains the extra fields EXTRA_DEVICE and EXTRA_CLASS. Can contain the extra fields EXTRA_NAME and/or EXTRA_RSSI if they are available.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_FOUND

In sequence of events, you would do the following:

1. `ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED` - Which will start discovery
2. `ACTION_FOUND` - Which will find a device
3. `ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED` - Which will end discovery

Comment: I've already tried this, but with no success. I can't find any bluetooth-device. I've located a bluetooth device beside my smartphone, so a bluetooth-device is available. With my smartphone I can find it. But not with my code.

Comment: There's a sample showing this here: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/BluetoothChat/DeviceListActivity.cs

Comment: I would highly recommend ensuring a couple things: 1) What type of Bluetooth are these devices? Classic or LE? 2) Does this sample with two Bluetooth Classic devices work for you?

Answer (score 0):

As for beginner, I would recommend looking into cross-platform libraries, e.g. https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le, https://github.com/aritchie/bluetoothle

This not only abstracts the platform-specific stuff, offers a simple interface to work with, but also give you multi-platform support out of the box.

I understand that this might be not the answer you're looking for, but in the end, this is what the main advantage of Xamarin is about - write once, run anywhere, etc.